# monitoring the effect of apps on registry and windows files?

Tags: vb.net, windows, file, registry, message

i am going to use vb.net to monitor the effect of apps on registry and files by using Windows Messages ( i am using : vb.net)

can any one help me how can i identify and receive  this windows messages.

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

try this:
 *The code sample demonstrates how to monitor registry change events in VB*
[https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/VBMonitorRegistryChange-27b67ef9#content][1]

Comment: thanks for that useful link ,, but there is any way to use windows messages ?? i think it will be better and faster :) i need to monitor all of registry values ....